# jQuery .remove() after ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I create `HTML` checkboxes dynamically using `PHP` and `MySQL`. They can look like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name ='chkDel' value='11'>
<input type='checkbox' name ='chkDel' value='18'>
<input type='checkbox' name ='chkDel' value='55'>
```

Then I have this `jQuery` script that checks if one or more checkboxes are checked and processes the information in a `PHP` file. For each checkbox checked it removes a row in a databse table.

```
$('#delete_absence_row').click(function() {
        var query_string = ''; 
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each( 
            function() { 
                if (this.checked) { 
                        query_string += "&chkDel[]=" + this.value; 
                    } 
            });
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../updateAbsence.php", 
        data: query_string, 
        success: 
            function(t) { 
                $("div#content_response").empty().append(t);
            }, 
        error: 
            function(){ 
                $("div#content_response").append("An error occured during processing"); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Now I would like to append a `.remove();` to each checkbox that are marked, that is all checkboxes that are in the `query_string` in the `success:function(t)`

I dont't know `jQuery` that much and the code above is a mix of different solutions I found on the web so bear with me.

How do I remove the checkboxes marked after a success function?

Comment: I've got an answer but it doesn't delete the row onClick using jQuery. It uses a php submit form to delete it, would that be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#delete_absence_row').click(function() {
        var query_string = '';
        var todelete = [];
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each( 
            function() { 
                query_string += "&chkDel[]=" + this.value;
                todelete.push(this);
            });
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../updateAbsence.php", 
        data: query_string, 
        success: 
            function(t) { 
                $("div#content_response").empty().append(t);
                $.each(todelete, function (i, e) {
                    $(e).remove();
                });
            }, 
        error: 
            function(){ 
                $("div#content_response").append("An error occured during processing"); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Thank's, this looks promising however I get this error in firebug: `TypeError: todelete.each is not a function`

Comment: I tried your edit but now I get `TypeError: e.remove is not a function`

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: Just one more thing Barmar, would it be possible to remove an entire HTML table row with the same ID as the checkbox has Value?

Comment: Yes, use `$(e).closest("tr").remove()`.